# Android Webview opens Chrome browser to accept Cookie

Tags: android, android-webview, android-cookiemanager

I want to show a Google Page in webview

I have used these option

```
mywebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
CookieManager.getInstance().setAcceptCookie(true);
CookieManager.getInstance().setAcceptThirdPartyCookies(mywebView, true);
```

But rather than page is opened Chrome with the page with the dialog to accept cookies.
How could I force cookie acceptance automatically without showing accept cookie window or at least if this is not possible make sure that window is opened in App itself?